# How can I create a drop-down box programmatically in Excel?

Tags: excel

I have a spread sheet which has a drop down in sheet1. Can anyone please tell me how to make a drop down in sheet3 of that same spread sheet assuming that it has three sheets named sheet1, sheet2, and sheet3.  The program is shown below.

```
  Range("A1").Select

  With Selection.Validation

    .Delete

    .Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, Operator:= _

    xlBetween, Formula1:="=$B$1:$B$3"/*Guess i need to make some change in this*/

    .IgnoreBlank = True

    .InCellDropdown = True

    .InputTitle = ""

    .ErrorTitle = ""


    .InputMessage = ""

    .ErrorMessage = ""

    .ShowInput = True

    .ShowError = True

  End With
```

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 2):

Define a [dynamic named range](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/830287) with the anchor as the insert point for your returned recordset.

Then, in the cell you wish to have the drop-down, type =(name of named range) - the drop-down options will then be whatever is returned from your database query.

Example:

Define a named range as "Options1" with formula `=OFFSET(Sheet1!$B$1,0,0,COUNTA(Sheet1!$B$1:$B$20),1)`

Set your database query to return the results to cell B1

Select cell A1 and open the Validation dialog (Data>Validation)

Select List and then enter `=Options1` as the Source

The above can be done programmatically by using

```
ActiveWorkbook.Names.Add Name:="Options1", RefersTo:="=OFFSET(Sheet1!$B$1,0,0,COUNTA(Sheet1!$B$1:$B$20),1)"

With Range("A1").Validation
    .Delete
    .Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, Operator:= _
        xlBetween, Formula1:="=Options1"
    .IgnoreBlank = True
    .InCellDropdown = True
    .InputTitle = ""
    .ErrorTitle = ""
    .InputMessage = ""
    .ErrorMessage = ""
    .ShowInput = True
    .ShowError = True
End With
```

Comment: Lunatik,How am i supposed to create a drop down in another sheet??
Can u plz help me out

Comment: A named range, as explained above, will work as a validation list on any sheet in the workbook.

Answer (score 0):

When you record a macro while using basic Excel functions to make a dropdown *(Data > Validate, then select Allow: list)*, you can look at the generated code and edit it to your liking. You can re-use the code afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

Create a "named range" out of $B$1:$B$3 then use the named range in the formula. If you do not want to use a named range then specify the sheet name in the formula, as in =Sheet1!$B$1:$B$3.

For help on naming cells in workbooks, see the "Name cells in a workbook" help topic and check out the "Name a cell or a range of cells" section.

- [Named Ranges in Microsoft Excel](http://www.officearticles.com/excel/named_ranges_in_microsoft_excel.htm)
  at
  http://www.officearticles.com/excel/named_ranges_in_microsoft_excel.htm
- [Excel Named Range](http://spreadsheets.about.com/od/exceltips/qt/named_range.htm) at
  http://spreadsheets.about.com/od/exceltips/qt/named_range.htm

Comment: Can u please elaborate it ?i m really new to these Macros

Answer (score 0):

If the data that you are using to populate the dropdown exists on each sheet, then you can select each sheet and add the validation.  See the code below.

```
Sub Dropdowns1()

With Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").Validation
        .Delete
        .Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, Operator:= _
        xlBetween, Formula1:="=$B$1:$B$3"
End With

With Worksheets("Sheet3").Range("A1").Validation
        .Delete
        .Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, Operator:= _
        xlBetween, Formula1:="=$B$1:$B$3"
End With

End Sub
```

If the data that you are using to populate the dropdown only exists on *sheet1*, then you need to first create a named range that refers to the data and then use the named range to pupulate the dropdown.

The code below creates a named range **MyList** that refers to the range *B1:B3* on *Sheet1*.  It then uses the named range on *Sheet1* and *Sheet3* to poulate a dropdown list.

```
Sub Dropdowns2()

ActiveWorkbook.Names.Add Name:="MyList", RefersTo:="=Sheet1!$B$1:$B$3"

With Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").Validation
        .Delete
        .Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, Operator:= _
        xlBetween, Formula1:="=MyList"
End With

With Worksheets("Sheet3").Range("A1").Validation
        .Delete
        .Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, Operator:= _
        xlBetween, Formula1:="=MyList"
End With
```

End Sub